# disabled text field throws 'Ext.fly is null' error when the mouse is moved over text field

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I am using ExtJs 4.1.1. I have a disabled textfield. When i move the mouse over the textfield, i get 'Ext.fly is null' JS error.This happenes only when the field is disabled. Please help.

```
 Ext.onReady(function () {
                    Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                        layout: 'anchor',
                        minHeight: 60,
                        items: [{
                                  xtype: 'textfield',                   
                                  anchor: '100%',
                                  disabled: true
                            }]
                    }).show();
                });
```

Comment: please provide a fiddle for this so it's easy for people to test.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this behavior with Extjs 4.1.0

Comment: Please note Error is only reproducible in IE.                 Following is the JSFiddle link:   http://jsfiddle.net/webfriend13/yZHnm/6/

Comment: Tried this on IE8 and still can't get the issue to happen.

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace of this error, a list of plugins you have in IE and a dump of the html on the page at runtime.

Comment: @Reimius: Thank you for quick reply. Please check this link: http://jsfiddle.net/CMYwg/                                                        Here is the stack trace ---------------------------------------------------Message: 'Ext.fly(...)' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 104777
Code: 0
URI: http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js


Message: 'Ext.fly(...)' is null or not an object
Line: 21
Char: 104777
Code: 0
URI: http://cdn.sencha.io/ext-4.1.1-gpl/ext-all.js

Answer (score 0):

You had a small syntax error on line 7. missing ",", which might be giving you the error but
i could not reproduce the error that you mentioned. Try this code if this fixes your problem

```
    Ext.onReady(function () {
            Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
                layout: 'anchor',
                minHeight: 60,
                items: [{
                          xtype: 'textfield',                   
                          anchor: '100%',
                          disabled: true
                    }]
            }).show();
        });
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did missed the ',' while specifying xtype config but even with ',' I still get the error. Make sure the text field is disabled and you move the mouse over the disabled textfield 3-4 times. I am using IE 8.